# Daynamic routing page in not coming, when use browser back button in next js

Tags: reactjs, next.js, browser-history, next-router, nextjs-dynamic-routing

In a Next.js project, I am coming across a situation where I get a new URL path from an API. And I have to update that URL path in the browser without reloading that page.

I am doing that with the help of [History.pushState()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/pushState)

```
window.history.pushState(nextState,nextTitle,nextURL);
window.history.replaceState(nextState,nextTitle,nextURL);
```

With help of `History.pushState()` I am able to update the URL in the browser without reloading that page. But If after I change that URL multiple times and change to some other page. Then if I start pressing the browser back button, I am not able to get that page with the last URL path showing in the browser.

Only that last URL path shows up in the browser URL input, but that page data is not reflected.
Attaching the sample code and reproducing steps video link below. Any help and suggestions are appreciated.

[Source Code](https://github.com/PraveenPal4232/dynamic-routing)

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/dynamic-routing-nextjs-rrs90x)

[Reproducing Steps](https://share.vidyard.com/watch/q5xErQ5V2oDG4vUgkBVhyK?)

Answer (score 1):

I am also facing same problem, after using `history.pushState()` browser back button will not work in that page, because according to browser you never went to that page.
That location doesn't exists in JavaScript history object.